# R Barchar does not work in For loop

Tags: r, for-loop, bar-chart

I am using `barchart` in *For loop* that goes on years, the `barchart` command is ok outside the loop, but inside - something goes wrong.

*Here is my code:*

```
for(i in 2006:2016){ 
  htr2 = htr[htr$year==i , ]
  barchart(year ~ y_kayam , groups=shlav, htr2, auto.key = list(columns = 2)  )
  Sys.sleep(5) }
```

*Here is my data*

```
year    vaada   shlav   tm38    y_kayam y_mevukash
2013    410         1   1       12.00
2013    410         2   1       12.00
2013    410         1   1       
2013    410         1   1       8.00    15.00
2013    410         3   1       8.00    15.00
2013    410         1           8.00    15.00
2013    410         1   1      15.00    28.00
2013    410        3    1      15.00    28.00
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen here?  AFAIK each loop iteration will simply overwrite the previous plot.

Comment: if you want to save copies of each plot, have a look at `dev.copy`

Comment: hi Tim , solution : need to activate barchart in print ()  command , i am making little animation using set of charts.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plotting the six plots nicely, I would use the [par](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) function.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))

for(i in 2006:2016){ 
  htr2 = htr[htr$year==i , ]
  barchart(year ~ y_kayam , groups=shlav, htr2, auto.key = list(columns = 2)  )
  Sys.sleep(5) }
```

Now, you can use [dev.copy()](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html) to save it as a PNG (or another image type).

```
dev.copy(png, 'myPlots.png')
dev.off()
```