# How to see saveHTML output ( "HTML file created at: index.html" )?

Tags: html, r, save

I am using  saveHTML  command to save set of charts, and I see nothing :

```
#install.packages("animation")
library(animation)
saveHTML({
    for(i in 2006:2010){ 
        htr2 = htr[htr$year==i , ]
        print(
            barchart( year ~ y_kayam, groups = shlav, htr2, auto.key = list(columns = 2))  
        )
        # plot(table (  htr2$y_mevukash , htr2$shlav  ) , ylab = "a yhd" , xlab="a shlav"  )
        #Sys.sleep(1) 
    }  
}, img.name = "Weibullpdf.html" )
```

What am I supposed to see?

I get the message

> ```
> HTML file created at: index.html
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to open the html file. You can use openFileInOS function from the [pander](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/pander.pdf) package.

```
openFileInOS("index.html")
```

Alternatively, you could just browse to the file which will be saved in your current working directory.

Comment: hi Foxhound , it did helped - thanks !    is there any way to pulish the file for othe users ?   is it possible to remove the code from the page ?

Comment: You want to save just the chart, if you refer to my answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034164/r-barchar-does-not-work-in-for-loop/41096556#41096556), I have amended it to show you how.